# slide ExpandableListView at DrawerLayout form right to left

Tags: android, android-layout

How to slide ExpandableListView at DrawerLayout form right to left

i want to show ExpandableListView  at right corner of screen , how can i do that ??

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change `android:layout_gravity="start"` to either `android:layout_gravity="end"` or `android:layout_gravity="right"` (using `end` will put the drawer on the left side of the screen for right-to-left configurations)

**EDIT**

It appears that the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is looking for a drawer on the same side as the action bar Home icon (`Gravity.START`), which would be the left side for left-to-right layout directions. If you will always have the drawer on the right, you could do something like this:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                mDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

If the drawer will always be opposite the action bar Home icon, you could use `Gravity.END` instead.

Comment: when i do that application crash

Comment: I am able to use `android:layout_gravity="end"` just fine with one of my little samples, so something else must be causing your crash.

Comment: 07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with absolute gravity LEFT
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1000)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:248)

Comment: 07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:141)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:170)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)

Comment: 07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Comment: 07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-23 14:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(20593):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I've edited my post to address your crash. (Next time please update your POST instead of putting this in the comments...)

Comment: thank you , It has become open from the right side but drawer at the left side , Whether Gravity.END or Gravity.RIGHT ,

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem since my app is Arabic and must begin from the right.

After testing all solutions here, I found that the best is:

- add this line in manifest : `android:supportsRtl="true"`
- in your activity add this code :  `getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);`
- in your listview don't use : `android:layout_gravity="right"`
  because if you use right you get the error in more Android versions like 4.0.4

The solution is the use of: `android:layout_gravity="start"`, because in this case the `listview` follows the gravity of the page.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the home button click in ActionBar that shows itself in line:

```
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    return true;
}
```

remove the lines I mentioned, where you have method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
   }
   //....
}
```

and replace it with:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }
    //...
}
```

Also do not forget to change the gravity of ListView to right: `android:layout_gravity="right"`