# NavigationDrawer with Top to bottom menu?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to use the NavigationDrawer as menu coming from top to bottom instead of left to right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547277/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-to-be-opened-from-right-to-left this is related to you.... Question..

Comment: That's a conflict to the Navigation bar. Better to place your NavigationDrawer from left side

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer which makes it possible to slide from any side by few lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

This is umano app's sliding up panel, I used this in my app, You can easily convert it to *top to bottom*

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 0):

Yes , ofcourse you can but it may create a confusion between the notification screen of android OS and your apps navigation drawer so its a good practice to put your navigation drawer either from left side or from right .

for more info you can have a look at this articles

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: where did you found that you can place the DrawerLayout from top to bottom? because I don't think this is possible.