# How to hide fragment like a navigation drawer by horisontal swipe?

Tags: android, xml, fragment, swipe

There is a listview wrapped by swiperefresh layout in fragment,
I want to hide this beyond the boundaries of the right corner of the screen
I cannot use Drawer Layout because I don't want to select items
My fragment:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/refresh"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.nick.music365.gui.fragments.ListFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/listview_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Navigation Drawer to be opened from right to left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547277/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-to-be-opened-from-right-to-left)

Comment: you can set your fragment as a drawer and swipe from right to left. Also you can omit ActionBarTogle part to not show the icon at top

Comment: You don't need to select anything in the drawer! it is just a placeholder for a fragment or view

Comment: in the layout of my activity i have 3 fragments, I dont have frame layout with content to replace