# how replace overflow and navigation drawer in action bar?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout

Hello guys i searched a lot but i got nothing how can i replace these two 
icon in my action bar  ? thanks a lot

i have already tried but result was not ok .

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" // here i tried change the gravity but didnt work
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: you want to replace icon only or you want to change drawer from left to right and overflow menu from right to left?

Comment: want to change drawer from left to right and overflow menu from right to left

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547277/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-to-be-opened-from-right-to-left

Comment: nope but i will thank you any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below in `AndroidManifest.xml` like

```
<application android:supportsRtl="true">
```

your code looks like

```
  <application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true" //here change
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

then

add below line of in your activity's `onCreate()` method

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);

Drawable drawable = context.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.your_overflowicon);
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
```