# How to change menu title programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android

Here is my menu:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:icon="@drawable/home"
                android:title="@string/bottom_basic_home" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/mancust"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts1"
                android:title="@string/customers" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/catalog"
                android:icon="@drawable/catalog"
                android:title="@string/catalog" />
        </group>

        <item android:title="About">    //my changes want to appear for this item
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/help"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_outline_black_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/help"
                        />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/codex_logout"
                        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
                        android:title="@string/logout" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </menu>
```

I am implementing navigation drawer in my Android application. How do I set a menu group item title programmatically?

Comment: Change your android:layout_gravity="end" . You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358114/2365507

Comment: Hello, you can use the android:layout_gravity as end or right

Comment: i want to change for only one item not for every item

Answer (score 0):

You can add id tag to your item in xml and find that item in the menu programmatically and set a new title.

Menu XML:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_title"
    android:title="About">
```

Java/Kotlin:

```
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val aboutTitle = navView.menu.findItem(R.id.about_title)
    aboutTitle.title = "New Title"
```