# How to move the drawer icon left to right in action bar..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-togglebutton

I want to place that icon left to right side.
Just want to know where should I change code?[image]

Comment: try this code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792237/slide-expandablelistview-at-drawerlayout-form-right-to-left/17792254#17792254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML layout file, make the gravity of your drawer Gravity: right or Gravity end instead of  Gravity:start

example

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end" //or you can use right also. 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

  />
```

Comment: I didn't mean the listview. The list view (drawer) is already coming form right. I want to know is the menu icon. It still staying at right side even though the drawer come from right.

Comment: Okay you will have to define a custom view for the action bar. See this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838955/set-actionbar-home-button-to-right-side