# How to make DrawerLayout slide from right to left?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I followed the example made by Google : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

It works perfectly, but i want to know, if it possible to make DrawerLayout slide from right to left ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible/17156831#17156831

Comment: Fixed, thanks Morrison