# Navigation Drawer From Right to Left

Tags: android

Hi I am implementing a navigation drawer. On that panel I have to show custom numeric pad. The panel working fine and numeric pad also. But the issue is the example from where I had taken was for listview. So on ActionBarDrawerToogle they have implemented onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item). So that I have to remove because when I am giving anything in relative layout i can only see the single line of numbers not the whole. Is there any other method that I can implement here. Please let me know.

The code that I modified is:

```
 private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
              //  if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    } else {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    }
               // }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

and the xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:background="#FFFFFF">

       <!-- <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="false"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            />
    </LinearLayout>-->

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/one"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/two"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/three"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/four"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/five"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/six"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a screen cap or better description of what you are seeing?  It is not clear from your description.

Comment: check out this -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible