# Navigation drawer from both left and right sides in one single activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am want to create navigation drawer from both left and right sides of home screen using single activity is it possible. On left side I want to open menu and on right side notification drawer. I searched a lot many sources but I only found navigation drawer either from left or right code in single activity. Any suggestions please to create navigation drawer from both sides using single activity...

Any source where I can be able to continue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible

Comment: Its a duplicate of a duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to think about using SlidingMenuLibrary with fragments. It's quite easy to use, and you can have your custom fragments on the left and right side of the screen, and all of this in a single activity (I know it's not a drawer, but you can make it work and look excatly the same).

The source: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Google Play Demo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example

Comment: I have already created navigation drawer from left side, but creating the same from right side is being issue from same single activity.