# Change Slider bar position to the Right side

Tags: java, android, sidebar

i am fresher in android development. i know very well how to implement native sidebar menu. but my problem is i want this sidebar menu on the right side of the screen.

So is it possible? please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can implement this on both side try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible/23286965#23286965

Answer (score 1):

It is affected by `layout_gravity`.

If `layout_gravity = start` then navigation drawer will open left to right and
 if `layout_gravity = end` then it will open right to left.

```xml
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/adventuresRTL"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#AAAAAA"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
```

Comment: i write this code in my app but it will gives an error like "05-16 06:13:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1941): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT"