# Android move slide menu from left to right

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm simply use this code to have slide menu in android applications but i can not move that to left side. by default this slide menu show in left side. how can i move it by default to right side

```
/*
* TAB LISTENER ON ------------------------------------------------------------
*/
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

//--------- TAB 1
ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
tab1.setTabListener(this);
tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search);
actionBar.addTab(tab1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible)

Answer (score 0):

The drawer list that you are using for example

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            **android:layout_gravity="start"**
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#2c3033"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
```

**android:gravity="end"** will make the list appear from Right to Left