# Android Dialog like component?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating my own side menu (hamburger menu) but I want the menu to be on top of my activity.

I don't want it to move my activity window.
All examples showed me how it moves the activity aside and brings the menu.

I tried doing it using a dialog component but I realized that dialog will always be in the center.

What android component should I be using to make a window come on top of my activity with an overlay?

Thank you.

Comment: DrawerLayout is the standard.

Comment: I tried that. How can I set my layout to the view? There is no `SetContentView` or `.Show` method.

Comment: I am using Xamarin platform and I can't seem to find DrawerLayout.  So I created my layout and I thought I would just apply animation to it.

Comment: @EvanB the user aksed for "I want the menu to be on top" not aside.

Comment: @Deuterium , the user said "I don't want it to move my activity window.", which leads me to believe they don't want the activity to shift while the drawer slides out. Currently, DrawerLayout sits on TOP of the activity; however, perhaps they want it to slide out from the top - but it's difficult to tell as this question is poorly written.

Comment: @EvanB yes, the user made a comment but deleted it, he said he wanted to come out from the right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use DrawerLayout which is part of the Android Support v4 Library.

Here's an example on how to use it from Xamarain.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer

See blog post for more detail:

http://motzcod.es/post/60427389481/effective-navigation-in-xamarin-android-part-1