# Android Slide menu from Right To Left

Tags: java, android

I have and android source code i want the slide menu to open from right to left

this is main activity as i tried to add Gravity right but it did not work any help in this problem

> Main Activity

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.universal.R;
import com.universal.rss.ServiceStarter;
import com.universal.web.WebviewFragment;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavDrawerCallback {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    public static String DATA = "transaction_data";

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String mWebUrl = null;
    boolean openedByBackPress = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boolean newDrawer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.newdrawer);

        if (newDrawer == true){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_alternate);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Helper.setStatusBarColor(MainActivity.this, getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor)); 
        }

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        if (newDrawer == true){
             mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.scrimInsetsFrameLayout, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
             mNavigationDrawerFragment.getDrawerLayout().setStatusBarBackgroundColor(
                     getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));
        } else {
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
        }

        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        //setting push enabled
        String push = getString(R.string.rss_push_url);
        if (null != push && !push.equals("")){
           // Create object of SharedPreferences.
           boolean firstStart = prefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

           if (firstStart){

               final ServiceStarter alarm = new ServiceStarter();

               SharedPreferences.Editor editor= prefs.edit();

               alarm.setAlarm(this);
               //now, just to be sure, where going to set a value to check if notifications is really enabled
               editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
               //commits your edits
               editor.commit();
           }

        }

        //Checking if the user would prefer to show the menu on start
        boolean checkBox = prefs.getBoolean("menuOpenOnStart", false);
        if (checkBox == true && null == mWebUrl){
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.openDrawer();
        }

          // New imageloader    
        Helper.initializeImageLoader(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rss_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, NavItem item){
        Fragment fragment;
        try {
            fragment = item.getFragment().newInstance();
            if (fragment != null && null == mWebUrl) {
                //adding the data
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String extra = item.getData();
                bundle.putString(DATA, extra);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                        .commit();

                setTitle(item.getText());

                if (null != MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar() && null != MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView()){
                    MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(
                            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
                } 

             } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
             }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment webview = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);

        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

            }  else if (webview instanceof WebviewFragment) {
            boolean goback = ((WebviewFragment)webview).canGoBack();
            if (!goback)
                super.onBackPressed();
        } else {   
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

> NavDrawerAdapter

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class NavDrawerAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<NavDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NavItem> mData;
    private NavDrawerCallback mNavDrawerCallbacks;
    private NavDrawerFragment mContext;

    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private int mTouchedPosition;

    public NavDrawerAdapter(List<NavItem> data, NavDrawerFragment context) {
        mData = data;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public NavDrawerCallback getNavigationDrawerCallbacks() {
        return mNavDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(NavDrawerCallback navDrawerCallback) {
        mNavDrawerCallbacks = navDrawerCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public NavDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,
            int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_top, viewGroup, false));
        } else if (i == 1) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_section, viewGroup, false));
        }

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mData.get(position).getType() == NavItem.TOP){
            return 0;
        } else if (mData.get(position).getType() == NavItem.SECTION) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NavDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            final int i) {

            Drawable drawable = null;
            if (mData.get(i).getDrawable() != 0) {
                drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                        mData.get(i).getDrawable());
            }

            if (mData.get(i).getType() == NavItem.ITEM) {
                setText(viewHolder.textViewItem, i, drawable);
                setBackgroundColor(i, viewHolder);
            } else if (mData.get(i).getType() == NavItem.EXTRA) {
                viewHolder.textViewExtra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.textViewItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                setText(viewHolder.textViewExtra, i, drawable);
                setBackgroundColor(i, viewHolder);
                viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            } else if (mData.get(i).getType() == NavItem.SECTION) {
                setText(viewHolder.textViewSection, i, drawable);
                viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            }
    }

    private void setBackgroundColor(int i,
            NavDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        if (mSelectedPosition == i || mTouchedPosition == i) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(viewHolder.itemView
                    .getContext().getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.selected_gray));
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    private void setText(TextView textView, final int i, Drawable drawable) {
        textView.setText(mData.get(i).getText());

        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null,
                null);

        textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touchPosition(i);
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    touchPosition(-1);
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touchPosition(-1);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mNavDrawerCallbacks != null)
                    mNavDrawerCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(i,
                            mData.get(i));
            }
        });
    }

    private void touchPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mTouchedPosition;
        mTouchedPosition = position;
        if (lastPosition >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        if (position >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    public void selectPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mSelectedPosition;
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewItem;
        public TextView textViewSection;
        public TextView textViewExtra;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            textViewExtra = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.extra_name);
            textViewSection = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_name);
        }
    }
}
```

> NavDrawerFragment

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;

public class NavDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavDrawerCallback {
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    private NavDrawerCallback mCallbacks;
    private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;

    private List<NavItem> mConfiguration;

    public void closeDrawer(int gravity) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(gravity);
    }
    public void openDrawer(int gravity) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(gravity);
    }
    public boolean isDrawerOpen(int gravity) {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(gravity);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_fragment, container, false);

        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final List<NavItem> NavItems = getConfiguration();
        NavDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(NavItems, NavDrawerFragment.this);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition, NavItems.get(mCurrentSelectedPosition));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavDrawerCallback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavDrawerCallback.");
        }
    }

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
        return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public void setActionBarDrawerToggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle) {
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = actionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

        //TODO This works (hides the drawer if there is only 1 item), but makes settings and favorites unreachable
        boolean newDrawer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.newdrawer);

        if (newDrawer == false && getConfiguration().size() == 1){
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }

        if (newDrawer == true && getConfiguration().size() == 2){
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }
    }

    public void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void closeDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    void selectItem(int position, NavItem item) {
        //If on start, item is section, change it.
        if (item.getType() == NavItem.SECTION || item.getType() ==  NavItem.TOP){
            position = position + 1;
            item = getConfiguration().get(position);
            selectItem(position, item);
            return;
        }

        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position, item);
        }
        ((NavDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, NavItem item) {
        //TODO we can also call this method here, but that won't set an initial item. 
        //mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position, item);
        if (item.getType() != NavItem.SECTION){
            selectItem(position, item);
        }
    }

    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    public void setDrawerLayout(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    }

    private List<NavItem> getConfiguration(){
        if (null == mConfiguration){
            mConfiguration = Config.configuration();

            boolean newDrawer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.newdrawer);

            if (newDrawer == true){
                mConfiguration.add(0, new NavItem("Header", NavItem.TOP));
            }
        }

        return mConfiguration;
    }

}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.universal.NavDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:layout="@layout/drawer_fragment"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible try looking at this post. May solve your problem

Comment: this is the Main layout

Comment: try to set `android:layout_gravity="start"` to `fragment_drawer`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this its worked for me

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
                layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_main_to_replcae_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.views.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_profile"
        android:name="com.views.fragments.ProfileFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I have placed my main.xml file check it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give this useful library a try :

[GitHub : SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

I have used this lib in my App :

[GitHub : OurDailyBread](https://github.com/Austin-Liang/OurDailyBread)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

it worked by this modification

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_name"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/dim_gray"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```