# Android Navigation drawer menu item icon color

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-view, slidingdrawer

I need to know how to set specific color for each menu item icon in navigation drawer.I am currently using latest navigation drawer in android studio 1.4.1 and also how can we include navigation header image view and name in our activity since the navigation header is in separate layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the specific problem you fail to solve? Nobody here is going to do your work for you. Especially when the official Android Developer page about the `NavigationDrawer` contains all the information to answer each and every one of your questions.

Comment: thank you. i will check with developers android and above mention link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include two navigation drawers in you layout file and assign gravity left for one and gravity right for another either dynamically or programmatically