# how to use sliding drawer jus like the below image with tabs and listview?

Tags: android

I am working on Registration page where I should allow the users to select country , Religion etc. so I thought of using sliding drawer to provide the list of countries . here my question is if the user clicks on a country field the sliding drawer should should appear from the right .How to add a sliding drawer with list view, the sliding drawer should slide from the right side and once the item from the list is selected the text should be displayed in the concerned field.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible)

Answer (score 0):

It is navigation drawer.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

You can use recycler view inside navigation drawer to show list.

But I really feel you should rethink about this, as a simple dropdown will suffice and  more intuitive to select a city from list of cities.

According to material design guidellines, these are the navigation drawer usage patterns. (Checkout navigation drawer section in this page)
http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns

Comment: Yes simple drop down list will suffice but it'll be very congested if the items in the list grow or in case of listing countries and cities. It'll not be that much appealing in case of mobile screen. So I just wanted to how to do this. Because i'm totally new to android.

Comment: I said so because of the guidelines or best practices. I feel this does not fall under use cases for navigation drawer. Instead you may try to use autocompletelistview with all country names as hints. while user types list gets filtered and user can select his country.