# How to change support.v7.widget.Toolbar drawer menu icon position?

Tags: android

I'm using support.v7.widget.Toolbar for create my actionbar. My question is that how I can change default drawer menu icon position to right corner?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible)

Comment: No, my point is change just menu icon to right side, not only drawer listview.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DrawerArrowDrawable` set in menu replace `Toolbar Navigation Icon`!