# Moving the Drawer Toggle From Left To Right in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

In my Activity I have a drawer list that pops from the right but I'm not able to move the drawer toggle from the left to the right side. Please if somebody can help me solve this issue.I just want to move the toggle to the right of the action bar.

```
package com.parse.starter;



import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class UserDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declaring Variables
private ListView DrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle DrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout DrawerLayout;
private String ActivityTitle;



final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_drawer);

    DrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    DrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    Button Sample = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

}

//Method To Add Items To The List View
private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] DArray = {"Job List", "Notifications", "Messages", "Log Out"};
    Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DArray);
    DrawerList.setAdapter(Adapter);
    DrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent i0 = new Intent(UserDrawer.this, Set_Info.class);
                startActivity(i0);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                //Intent i1 = new Intent(Drawer1.this, AddPatient.class);
                //startActivity(i1);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                //Intent i2 = new Intent(Drawer1.this, Notifications.class);
                //startActivity(i2);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                //Intent i3 = new Intent(Drawer1.this, Message_Log.class);
                //startActivity(i3);
            } else if (position == 4) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(UserDrawer.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i4);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}

private void setupDrawer() {
    DrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, DrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Menu");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(ActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    DrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(DrawerToggle);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item != null && item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
        if(DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
            //Notice the Gravity.Right
            DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }else{
            DrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }

   return false;
    }
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    DrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
public void SampleClick(View view) {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(UserDrawer.this,Set_Info.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}


}
```

Comment: You gotta start by assigning left gravity to your ListView. Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible

Comment: I want to remove the toggle in the action bar...my list is already moved to the right

Comment: I think you can try using a custom toolbar. Its pretty easy and would give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: can you help me I'm new to android studio

Comment: Check out [this](http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example) tutorial. Just think of toolbar as a parent layout and include the buttons you want inside it. Then simply set onClick listeners on these toolbar buttons to open or close your drawer.