# making a View like Fragment Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I would like to make a Fragment show up just like a `Fragment Drawer` would, but not only to a list of intents.

(If you don't know what I mean by Fragment Drawer):
`Google` products such as Gmail, "Google app", Google Play...
 utilize them frequently.
The Fragment Drawer is a menu on one of these apps created by swiping from left to right or clicking the "Hamburger" button.

I would like to highlight the distinction between what I want and the Fragment Drawer is: I would like to be able to place `TextViews`, `ImageViews`, and `Buttons` inside of it as if it were a normal fragment in which I could just inflate a layout in it and I would rather it come from the right instead.

If a visual representation is needed I would be happy to try my hand at making one.

Comment: The drawer in a `DrawerLayout` can be any `View` you want, and the side it's aligned to is just determined by its `layout_gravity` attribute. What problems are you having, specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible)

Comment: Oh, @MikeM. I'm sorry, I forgot to realize that the ListView is programed by the app dev. My post may just be a dud now. Thanks and I will get back to you if I have any problems... Sorry!

Comment: Sure. Btw, it doesn't have to be a `ListView`, if that's what you're thinking. It can be any `View`. You could make it a `FrameLayout`, e.g., if you want to load a `Fragment` into it. Or you could make it a `LinearLayout`, a `RelativeLayout`, etc., that you can put any number of other `View`s in.